# Why should I use em, and not % for fonts?

Tags: responsive-design, css, font, font-sizes

If ems essentially give you a result that is a percentage of the base font, what advantage is there to using it, rather than % for font sizing? I have looked around, and haven't really seen anything that implies that the two behave differently from each other. Is there a cascading issue?

Answer (score 6):

EM and PERCENT are both very similar, the only difference between the two can be observed when changing text size on the client browser.

[image: Comparison]

#### Summary

> In theory, the **em** and **rem** units are the new and upcoming standard for font sizes on the web, but in practice, the percent unit seems to provide a more consistent and accessible display for users.

Original article by Kyle Schaeffer: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Thanks @Igorek! That is really helpful for base-font sizing, though it doesn't get into the reasoning behind his use of ems: "when I create a new design, I will use percent on the body element (body { font-size: 62.5%; }), and then use the em unit to size it from there." I'm wondering why he wouldn't just use % for everything, since ems ultimately amounts to a % of the base font.

Comment: I can speculate that it does not make much sense to mix % and EMs. Now, as I mentioned above EM and REM both are becoming a new standard and based on the difference between EM and REM - REM offers less headaches and better control w/o having to worry about inheritance (you do have to worry about font inheritance with using EM and %).

Comment: This article is 7 years old, ancient in web design terms.  Important current considerations like mobile experience barely existed then.  Maybe it is still true, but do you have any more recent information?

Comment: @dan1111, the question was "what is the difference", which that article covers in very good detail. That difference is still true to this day. If you are interested in a question "What should I use?", there is a more recent [article from 2014 found on CSS-Tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/) website that talks about rem and em usage. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: My questions was less a general "what is the difference" than what are the fundamental advantages or disadvantages of basing my designs on one vs. the other, since they both seem to be about a relationship to some base style. I really wasn't sure if there was some behavioral difference between the two (e.g. cascading happens differently, ???), or if they really are basically the same, and i would be equally well off regardless of which one I use.

Comment: @Rath_Er. The inly difference between the two is what i described (if a person will be controlling text size via a browser). An article I've linked in comments shows how you can use REM and EM together and I agree with such practice. Think modular design

Answer (score 2):

In terms of behaviour, there is no difference. The difference cited above is simply a buggy browser implementation, in my opinion.

I just did a quick test in current Chrome and Firefox, and there is no difference in sizing of child elements : smaller; : larger when the parent is either 1em or 100%. I would very be surprised if this bug was present in any modern browsers; browsers have come a long way in seven years.

The only difference, in practical terms, is the extra character required to use %. Why use 4 when you can use 3?

Beyond that I believe the only difference is the historical precedent. There are hundreds of years of tradition behind setting type size in ems.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I suspected. It seems kind of funny that the field of user experience has adopted a measurement that is unfamiliar to a large number of people who would be interacting with the code, rather than something as standard and widely understood as %.